# Write to CSV a List of Tuples of Lists

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I have the following variable:

```py
data = [(['a', 'b', '3'], ['c', 'a', 'r']),
        (['*', '[', 'e'], ['33', 'gh', 'ew']),
        (['23^', 're#', '4$'], ['tr', 'fF', '5%'])]
```

I want to write `data` into a CSV file as follows:

```
a c
b a
3 r

* 33
[ gh
e ew

23^ tr
re# fF
4$ 5%
```

Note that after each iteration I have a black space in between.

---

I tried:

```py
import csv 
with open ('train.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in dataset:
        writer.writerows(row)
```

But does not work properly.

Comment: That's not a CSV you're trying to write, though?

Comment: Indeed, yes. I mentioned CSV to make to task easy. I don't know how to name such files.

Comment: that's kinda a csv, but those blank lines mean its not quite. It looks like you want two space separated columns. Can the values themselves have spaces in them? If so, how are they to be escaped so that you don't confuse an interior space with a separator?

Comment: @Joe It seems your file is arbitrary in its entirety.  What purpose does it serve?

Comment: The values do not have space. Space appears in a row only after writing each tuple.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I want to end up with something like this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cswangjiawei/pytorch-NER/master/data/eng.train

Comment: But _why_? It seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley - how is it arbitrary? its clearly using a blank line to delimit the sublists. I think the only question is whether the data itself needs any csv special sauce (separators and escapes).

Comment: @tdelaney Arbitrary in that it's not a standards-conforming serialization format.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you are writing space separated rather than comma separated, it looks like you need to transpose the inner 2d structures. You could use `writer.writerows(list(zip(*row)))`

Comment: Or in fact just `writer.writerows(zip(*row))`

Comment: Many thanks for all! The answer @Chris provided below works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get it done.

```
data = [(['a', 'b', '3'], ['c', 'a', 'r']),
        (['*', '[', 'e'], ['33', 'gh', 'ew']),
        (['23^', 're#', '4$'], ['tr', 'fF', '5%'])]


with open('train.txt','w') as f:
    
    for x in  [tuple(zip(x[0],x[1])) for x in data]:
        for r in x:
            f.write(' '.join(r) + '\n')
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: This writes a blank line at  the end of the file. Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Since this format doesn't conform to CSV rules you can just use regular string formatting to write the lines. The one trick is in the handling of the blank line separator. Assuming you don't want an extra blank line at the bottom of the output file, you can get a bit creative. Write the separator before writing each group, but start with a blank string and switch it to the real separator after the first write.

```
data = [(['a', 'b', '3'], ['c', 'a', 'r']),
        (['*', '[', 'e'], ['33', 'gh', 'ew']),
        (['23^', 're#', '4$'], ['tr', 'fF', '5%'])]

with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
    group_sep = "" # group separator written first to avoid extra blank
                   # line at end of file.
    for group1, group2 in data:
        file.write(group_sep)
        group_sep = "\n"
        for cell1, cell2 in zip(group1, group2):
            file.write(f"{cell1} {cell2}\n")
```